# Finding the distance between the point $(3,7)$ and $x = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

In the paper of maths, there was an M.C.Q.S.:

> The distance of the point $(3,7)$ from $x = 0$ is
>
> - $3$
> - $7$
> - $10$
> - $8$

So can anyone tell me what was the correct answer and how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: draw the line x=0, and then the point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting it as the distance of the point $(3, 7)$ from the line $x = 0$, that is to say the ordinate axis.

How do you find the distance between a point and a line? read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

In this case it's particularly easy to see that the distance is $3$, but I'll leave to you how to fill the details